# Create 3d image hover effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, hover

I want to create this effect but with javascript not in pure css as he did. And no scss also just css It'll be good. [codepen](https://codepen.io/onediv/pen/BprVzp)

```css
.picture-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-self: center;
  align-items: center;

  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
}
.picture-frame {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  padding: 5%;

  border: solid 1px #000;
}
.picture {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div class="picture-container first-picture horizontal-small">
          <div class="picture-frame">
            <img
              id="secondPic"
              src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"
              alt="picture of a brick house"
              class="picture middle-right"
            />
         </div>
</div>
<html>
```

I'm also using Vuejs if it changes something for this

Comment: You have a Vuejs nice working example here: https://codepen.io/jouanmarcel/pen/JjjZRrW

Comment: @Kapcash feel free to post that one as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ***transform*** styling to get the 3D effect. Checkout my code below

```js
var card = document.getElementsByClassName('card');

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {  
  var ax = -(window.innerWidth/2- e.pageX)/20;
  var ay = (window.innerHeight/2- e.pageY)/10;
  document.getElementById("cards").style.transform = "rotateY("+ax+"deg) rotateX("+ay+"deg)"; 
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700);
 body {
     background: #edf2f4;
     perspective: 1000px;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     display: flex;
     height: 100vh;
     font-family: "Playfair Display", georgia, serif;
}
 .card {
     pointer-events: none;
     transform: translateZ(0);
     padding: 30px;
     background: white;
     border-radius: 5px;
     width: 400px;
     height: 200px;
     margin: auto;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
     backface-visibility: hidden;
     display: flex;
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
     position: relative;
}
 .card:after {
     content: " ";
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 10px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     left: 0;
     bottom: -50px;
     box-shadow: 0 30px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
 .card .card-content {
     margin: auto;
     text-align: center;
     transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
 .card h1 {
     transform: translateZ(100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="cards" class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <h1>Just hover around</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```